# how to weave my website into phonegap app

Tags: javascript, cordova

am trying to build my first app using phonegap desktop.

but there is something basic that i dont understand

i have a (js +html )website i developed on my local machine.

its pure client it doesnt have any server side.

i want the phonegap app created by phonegap desktop to open my site.

i read that i need to put my site into the www folder in the app.

but do i need to put the js files in the app js folder and the style  file in

the  css folder etc?

what do i do with my own index.html file?

how do i make the app index html file call my html file?

Lord Corwin of Amber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you want to package your site with the app

You simply copy your entire site with index.html into www directory which will load your homepage as a local page and delete existing data of www before copying, for more info [see this](http://antonylees.blogspot.in/2013/02/launch-website-as-mobile-app-using.html)